# Create Shapefile of all overlapping features from single Shapefile

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, overlapping-features

I need to create a Shapefile out of another Spahefile that consists all overlaps of features within the initial Shapefile.

I'm sure there is a simple solution using ArcMap or QGIS, but at the moment I am just lost and somehow I struggle to find something via search engines although I am aware that this question must have been asked a thousand times.
The screenshot shows the desired result. My new Shapefile should only consist the darker parts independent on the number of overlapping features.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the result you are after use the [**Intersect (Analysis)**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/0008/00080000000p000000.htm) tool with only one input feature class. If you read about **[How Intersect works](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/How_Intersect_works/00080000000z000000/)** it says:

> Intersect can run with a single input. In this case, instead of
>   discovering intersections between the features from the different
>   feature classes or layers, it will discover the intersections between
>   features within the single input. This can be useful to discover
>   polygon overlap and line intersections (as points or lines).

Comment: Thank you. Even me, I tried to use the tool at first but it created an empty output. This empty output seems to be created because of another issue, that I have to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

In arcgis, you can use the Clip tool under Analysis Tools -> Extract. This will export out a new shapefile where any overlap occurs.

Comment: So you mean I take the same SHP as Input and Clip Feature? Wouldn't that result in a new SHP that is the same to the initial one?

Comment: Nevermind, I thought you had two shapefiles but it looks like its all one shapefile but categorized separately. I would use PolyGeo suggestion on Intersect.